# using elasticsearch query on springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kotlin

I have this query working, I have the expected results using it in kibana.

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_shape" : {
                    "SitePoint" : {
                        "shape": {
                           "type": "polygon",
                           "coordinates" : [
                            [[18.85491,-33.92305],
                            [18.8604,-33.9319],
                            [18.85618,-33.9399],
                            [18.84809,-33.94153],
                            [18.85491,-33.92305]]
                           ]
                        },
                        "relation": "within"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to build something solid using ElasticsearchRepository with Kotlin or Java, I really don't find much about it on the internet or I don't understand the documentation as I should.

```
val coor = mutableListOf(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate(18.85491,-33.92305),
                org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate(18.8604,-33.9319),
                org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate(18.85618,-33.9399),
                org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate(18.84809,-33.94153),
                org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate(18.85491,-33.92305))

        val query = QueryBuilders
                .geoShapeQuery("objects", ShapeBuilders.newPolygon(coor))
                .relation(ShapeRelation.WITHIN)
```

just running this to see the query i have a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.locationtech.spatial4j.exception.InvalidShapeException`

Can someone help me?

Comment: do you have `spatial4j` lib dependency?

Comment: no, i have only `org.locationtech.jts / 1.16.1` i will add `spatial4j` and try

Comment: Now I have no console error, but I can not affect my index with this method.
How do I modify this method to fetch all objects within my index `my_index` that are within the polygon?

Comment: update your question with new issue. what is expected? what's actual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a bit of research this way I can use Spring's JPA to query

```
val filter = QueryBuilders.geoShapeQuery("SitePoint", ShapeBuilders.newPolygon(coordinates)).relation(ShapeRelation.WITHIN)

            val searchQuery = NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                    .withQuery(matchQuery("id", id))
                    .withFilter(filter)
                    .build()

            return template.queryForList(searchQuery, MyClass::class.java)
```